# Print from jq using a wild card (or coalesce to first non null)

Tags: json, jq, kubectl, coalesce

I have the following command:

> `kubectl get pod -A -o=json | jq -r '.items[]|select(any( .status.containerStatuses[]; .state.waiting or .state.terminated))|[.metadata.namespace, .metadata.name]|@csv'`

This command works great.  It outputs both the namespace and name of my failing pods.

But now I want to add one more column to the results.  The column I want is located in one (and only one) of two places:

- .status.containerStatuses[].state.*waiting*.reason
- .status.containerStatuses[].state.*terminated*.reason

I first tried adding `.status.containerStatuses[].state.*.reason` to the results fields array.  But that gave me an `unexpected '*'` compile error.

I then got to thinking about how I would do this with SQL or another programming language.  They frequently have a function that will return the first non-null value of its parameters.  (This is usually called coalesce).  However I could not find any such command for `jq`.

**How can I return the `reason` as a result of my query?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jq has a counterpart to "coalesce" in the form of `//`.
For example, `null // 0` evaluates to 0, and chances are that it will suffice in your case, perhaps:

```
.status.containerStatuses[].state | (.waiting // .terminated) | .reason
```

or

```
.status.containerStatuses[].state | (.waiting.reason // .terminated.reason )
```

or similar.

However, `//` should only be used with some understanding of what it does, as explained in detail on the jq FAQ at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#or-versus-

If `//` is inapplicable for some reason, then the obvious alternative would be an `if ... then ... else ... end` statement, which is quite like C's `_ ? _ : _` in that it can be used to produce a value, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
.status.containerStatuses[].state
| if has("waiting") then .waiting.reason
  else .terminated.reason
  end
```

However, if `containerStatuses` is an array, then some care may be required.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to go with `coalesce`:

```
# Stream-oriented version
def coalesce(s):
  first(s | select(. != null)) // null;
```

or if you prefer to work with arrays:

```
# Input: an array
# Output: the first non-null element if any, else null
def coalesce: coalesce(.[]);
```

Using the stream-oriented version, you could write something along the lines you had in mind with the wildcard, e.g.

```
coalesce(.status.containerStatuses[].state[].reason?)
```